# Defing Brush in static resource and using it as DynamicResource

Tags: wpf, xaml

I need to extract one brush from one control, and save it in resources, so I can later use it in xaml bindings.

This brush can be any type of brush, so I cannot just daclare specific type of brush, like SolidColorBrush.

Lets name the brush as themeBackground. Also, this brush can be changed while the application is running, so I cannot use bindings like this:

```
<Control Background={StaticResource themeBackground}" />
```

but I need to use DynamicResource instead

```
<Control Background={DynamicResource themeBackground}" />
```

Bindings like relativeSource cannot be used in this case, so I need to store this brush in resources to be publicly available.

Anyone has any ideas how to declare this brush in xaml (I cannot declare it as Brush), and how to use it in bindings to set Background? Storing / updating the actual value in resources is not a problem.